# SQL - COMPARING MULTIPLE FIELD IN A TABLE

Tags: sql

I want to compare 3 fields value in a table.
example:column 1 - 10 items
         column 2 - 7 items with 3 Null
         column 3 - 4 items with 6 null

anybody can help me!

```
               items          column1    column2       column3
                  1               BK1    NULL            BK1
                  2               RK1    RK1             RK1
                  3               SK1    SK2             NULL
                  4               AK1    AK1             AK2
                  5               CK1    CK2             CK2
                  6               DK1    NULL            NULL
                  7               EK1    EK1             NULL
                  8               FK1    NULL            NULL
                  9               GK1    GK1             NULL
                  10              HK1    NULL            NULL
```

Reuslt

```
                items            column1 column2       column3  RESULT
                  1               BK1    NULL            BK1    OK
                  2               RK1    RK1             RK1    OK
                  3               SK1    SK2             NULL   NOT EQUAL
                  4               AK1    AK1             AK2    NOT EQUAL
                  5               CK1    CK2             CK2    NOT EQUAL
                  6               DK1    NULL            NULL   OK
                  7               EK1    EK1             NULL   OK
                  8               FK1    NULL            NULL   OK
                  9               GK1    GK1             NULL   OK
                  10              HK1    NULL            NULL   OK
```

Comment: Edit you query. Doesn't make much sense as it is now.

Comment: Add table definitions, sample data and expected outout!

Comment: We can't figure out what you are asking for without any info...

Comment: This my table look like

Comment: Great. And what's the output you want, if you have the table data as above?

Comment: Could you add the result set you expect?

Comment: i have to compare all three field and pull the equal matching and non matching items

Comment: result items1 is equal, item3 is non equal

Comment: So what's the result you want?

Comment: need to skip the null value and compare the remaining fields

Answer (score 1):

I hope following can be helpful

```
select * from tablename            
where (column1 is not null and column2 is not NULL and column3 is not NULL)
and (column1 = column2 or column2 = column3 or column3 = column1 )
```

Please check SQLFiddle example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe38f/1

Comment: It is omitting the null value items

Comment: I need query to compare the field with null value, Please see the Result in Item number 1

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename
where
    (c1 is null or ((c2 is null or c1 = c2) and (c3 is null or c1 = c3)))
 and
    (c2 is null or ((c1 is null or c1 = c2) and (c3 is null or c2 = c3)))
 and
    (c3 is null or ((c1 is null or c1 = c3) and (c2 is null or c2 = c3)))
```

Comment: Need to add any extra bracket